# Total participation constraint PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, constraints, relational-database

I'm looking for a way to write a total participation constraint in postgreSQL.

I have this kind of ER Diagram with other attributes and relationships :

|Release| ====  ----- |Country|

I've written the three tables below, but how can I obtain the "at least one" constraint represented by the thick line between release and release_country.

```
CREATE   TABLE   country( id   integer   PRIMARY   KEY, name   text   NOT   NULL);

CREATE TABLE release(
    id   integer   PRIMARY   KEY,
    title   text   NOT   NULL,
    status   integer,
    barcode   numeric(26,0),
    packaging   CHAR(22),
    FOREIGN   KEY(status)   REFERENCES   release_status
);

CREATE   TABLE   release_country(
    release   integer, 
    country   integer,
    day   integer,CHECK   (day   >=   0   AND   day   <=   31), 
    month   integer,CHECK   (month   >=   0   AND   month   <=   12), 
    year   integer,
    PRIMARY   KEY(release,country),
    FOREIGN   KEY(release)   REFERENCES   release, 
    FOREIGN   KEY(country)   REFERENCES   country
);
```

Comment: This can be done with triggers, but you must ensure that you take a `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR KEY UPDATE` lock on the parent row (country) to guard against concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm totally novice in PostgreSQL, could you show me how to write the appropriate trigger please ?

Comment: I'll let someone else do that, won't have time to write a full example.

Comment: Not related but I would turn `(day, month, year)` into a `date`